# Magento2 use default password validation in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, validation, password

Can anyone let me know how to use default magento server side validation for password field in my custom module password string?I have dealer registration form and i have password field there and i want to use magento password server side validation there.

I tried to use checkPasswordStrength() function of core Magento by calling that function in my module but it throws following error:
few argument passed in __construct() method.

Please let me know which extra arguments i will have to pass or any other way?